# How can i install an old samba version on Oracle Linux 7.5

Tags: redhat, samba, rpm

Apologies if this is a lame question but i don't have much experience with subject..

I know that there are a bunch of posts regarding this but i wasn't able to find a proper solution...

I running Oracle Cloud 7.5 (Red Hat 7.5) on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure with samba 4.9 and i need to install Samba 3.6.23, when i use `yum --showduplicates list samba` i can only see 4.x...

How can i install this specif version of samba?
Can i download the rpm from somewhere and install it manually? (found one for Cent Os 6 but i don't know if it's 'compatible' with Oracle linux)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not install Samba 3.6.23, it is DEAD. It is very insecure and I can see no good reason to use it instead of a supported version of Samba.

Comment: I totally agree, but it's a requirement from a Software (ERP) we are using on-prem and will be needed on oracle cloud environment...

I"m try with no luck until now with .rpm file but i'm facing package dependencies and version problems...

Comment: I would find another, more up to date ERP if I were you, especially if dictates what version of Samba you must use. The Samba 3.6 series went eol back in 2015 and there have been numerous CVE update to Samba then, none of which have been backported and you want to use it in the cloud ?

Comment: I agree with you Rowland... if it was my call i would leave it to the company that created the ERP to update their software, i was going to use Samba 4.10 for this case...

I'm strongly recommending internally that we use the least available version due to security and other problems from version 3.6.23 but the still want to use it... for now...

but i'll use this post as a feedback from the community about the implications we might have if we somehow make this version work...Thanks